# How to inject a bean into a POJO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My goal is to inject `PasswordEncoder` to a `CreateUserModel` POJO.

I put the `@Bean PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder` in a config class.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
   @Bean
   PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
     return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
   }
}
```

This is how I wish my POJO looks like:

```
public class CreateUserModel {
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String name;
  private String role;

  private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

  public CreateUserModel(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, String username, String password, String name, String role) {
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    this.name = name;
    this.role = role;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getRole() {
    return role;
  }
}
```

This is how I would use the `CreateUserModel` POJO.

```
@RestController
public class OrganizationController {
  @PostMapping("/organization/createuser")
  public CreateUserModel createUser(@RequestBody CreateUserModel user) {
    return user;
  }
}
```

A user will send a POST request with a body:

```
{
  "username": "user",
  "passsword": "secret",
  "name": "user client",
  "role": "1"
}
```

My expected result for sending POST request to `/organization/createuser` is:

```
{
  "username": "user",
  "passsword": "alv4ko023j4v2lkralfj",
  "name": "user client",
  "role": "1"
}
```

My actual result, the server throws

```
2021-02-20 21:32:26.614  WARN 202592 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.satpamspringboot.model.organization.CreateUserModel`, problem: `java.lang.NullPointerException`; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.satpamspringboot.model.organization.CreateUserModel`, problem: `java.lang.NullPointerException`
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 1]]
```

The only solution I can think of is to use the DTO pattern, which require 5 separate files:

1. File with @RestController, @PostMapping, @RequestBody
2. File for the DTO object.
3. File with @Service
4. File with @Mapper
5. File for the DAO object.

By injecting `PasswordEncoder` to the `CreateUserModel` POJO, it will reduce the boilerplate:

1. Combine the DTO and DAO object.
2. Remove File with @Service.

Comment: What are the details of the error message? 
Also, to tell SpringBoot to inject your own managed bean, you need to annotate your Config class with @Configuration.

Comment: Are you seeing any CORS error in browser or Postman or tool used to send post request?
Enable the debug log level and check the logs..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--the POJO would still need to be wired by Spring; you can't escape telling Spring about required wiring. That said, if you want User to be explicitly not-Spring, then why do that encoding in User at all? Wire the controller with the encoder.

Comment: Is the config annotated with @component or indicated as config to spring.

Comment: @Tim The issue is that there's no way for Spring to know it's supposed to be wiring User with an encoder impl without being told to do so.

Comment: @kidfrom When posting about an error you need to include complete details. Here it's fairly obvious, but an "internal service error" provides no generally-useful information: include relevant portions of the stack trace.

Comment: @OnomeSotu sorry, I forget to write the `@Configuration` in the post, I did check the source code and I confirmed that `@Configuration` is present.

Comment: @DaveNewton I never wire POJO before, to clarify, I never add annotation to the POJO class for model e.g `CreateUserModel` POJO, I also avoid to use `@Autowired`, instead I use the constructor, do I make a mistake?